# Error in SQlite INSERT INTO statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android and working on an Android app. Unfortunately, I get an error when trying to insert data from intents into an `SQlite` database. I want to insert the results of a scan to the database, but I get error messages. I want to insert two scan results from Intents - SCAN RESULT and SCAN RESULT FORMAT - into the database.

This is the **Logcat:**

```
08-22 12:27:11.141 27724-27724/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant, PID: 27724
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant/de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.AndroidBarcodeQrExample}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SCANDATA": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SCANDATA SCANDATA  SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "SCANDATA": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SCANDATA SCANDATA  SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT)
#################################################################
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4005)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4048)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1479)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SCANDATA": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SCANDATA SCANDATA  SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT
#################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "SCANDATA": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SCANDATA SCANDATA  SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT)
#################################################################
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
at de.die_web_agenten.www.runinstant.AndroidBarcodeQrExample.onActivityResult(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.java:119)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6441)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4001)
... 10 more
```

This is the code with the **SQLite statement:**

```
  private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{ TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT},
                null, null, null, null, null
        );


        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT},
                new int[]{R.id.ScanFormatView, R.id.ScanResultView, R.id.ScanIdView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                helper = new TaskDBHelper(AndroidBarcodeQrExample.this);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();

                String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO SCANDATA %s  %s ",
                        TaskContract.TABLE,
                        TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT,
                        TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT
                );
                sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
                updateUI();


                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + (contents));
                Log.d("BDebugTag", "Value: " + (format));
                updateUI();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Informationen erfolgreich gespeichert!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            }

        }

    }

    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
        this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
    }
```

Where is the error in the code? Any hints and help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to debug the code.

Comment: your query is wrong, it is just printing `INSERT INTO SCANDATA SCANDATA  SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT`

Comment: If you find it hard to work with raw SQL, there are Java wrappers for it, such as `SQLiteDatabase#insert()` and `ContentValues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you probably want to do is insert `contents` and `format` to `TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT` and `TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT` respectively. This is how you should create the statement -

```
String.format("INSERT INTO SCANDATA (%s,%s) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
       TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT,
       TaskContract.Columns.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT,
       contents,
       format
);
```

Comment: String literals need to be quoted, or preferably passed in as variables (`?` in SQL and values in the `Object[]` arg).

Comment: Ah! I always miss that! Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote wrong the syntax. You must use the following.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)] VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```